# openSUSE Leap 42.1 - Kontact won't launch

Tags: linux, opensuse, kde-4, kde-plasma-5, pim

I'm using openSUSE 42.1 with Plasma 5, and the PIM application Kontact has stopped to work: suddenly it won't start when launched, (I mean that one day it worked, the subsequent stopped to do it).

I've tried to run it from a console, this is the output:

```
json_parser - syntax error found,  forcing abort, Line 1 Column 0 
kontact(7039)/kdeui (kdelibs): No such XML file "/home/stefano/.kde4/share/apps/kontact/default-.rc"
```

The single applications that compose the full suite, when launched individually, start and work normally; if I launch Kmail, KAddressbook, Korganizer and so on I don't experience any problem, they are fully functional.

Despite being on Plasma5, I'm using the KDE4 version of the PIM suite and of all its programs; during the installation the system has automatically chosen this version, even if the repositories contain the other one.

Comment: Have you tried just `touch`ing home/stefano/.kde4/share/apps/kontact/default-.rc?

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by deleting the file `~/.kde4/share/config/kontactrc`.